# SQL Native Client, linked server error Only on Deletes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server, sql-server-native-client

We are using a SQL Native Client to connect to a local SQL Server 2005 from a Borland application. It will fine for selects, inserts, and updates. When we delete we get the error:

> Could not find server
>   `SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS` in
>   sys.servers. Verify that the correct
>   server name was specified. If
>   necessary, execute the stored
>   procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add
>   the server to sys.servers

The default instance, the only instance, is `SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS`, and we are not using linked servers. Any ideas? I believe we moved the MDF and LDF files to a new server for this DB, and then reattached it.

**Update 1**

There is no SQL. This is all happening through programmatic interaction with cursors. It is an ODBC driver using ADO. You run TableObj->Delete to remove the record.

Comment: Can you post your SQL for the DELETE stmt? Sounds suspiciously like a foreign key violation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I ran

```
SELECT @@servername
```

That returned the old host name of the box. I than ran

```
sp_dropserver 'OLDHOSTNAME\SQLEXPRESS'
go
sp_addserver 'NEWHOSTNAME\SQLEXPRESS', local
```

I then got

> Server 'NEWHOSTNAME\SQLEXPRESS' is not
>   configured for DATA ACCESS

I ran

```
sp_serveroption 'ICS-POS3-NEW\SQLEXPRESS', 'data access' , 'true'
```

This got me the error

> Transaction context in use by another
>   session

Which is because of linked servers. I found that the local option on the add server did not take affect until I restarted the server. I restarted, then it just worked.